# Angular 2+ async execution of setTimeOut on a single object within array

Tags: angular, asynchronous, settimeout

I'm new to angular and learning :) just gotta ask about async execution of functions if its possible so to say.
The code below is running in sync but is there a way to execute each object independently or to say async.

An object arrives to array, from that point its timeout is triggered and lasts as long as duration is set, independently for each object.

The code:

```
const objArr = [
  { key: 1, item: 'Orange apples', durationInMs: 4000 },
  { key: 2, item: 'Green apples', durationInMs: 2000 },
  { key: 3, item: 'Pink apples', durationInMs: 8000 },
];

// Remove from array after its duration ends
objArr.forEach(item => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    objArr.filter(element => element.key !== item.key);
    // or some other function to remove element from array
  }, item.durationInMs);
});
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? As it stands, your for loop will queue each of the `setTimeout`s, so it should fire `Green apples` after 2 seconds, then `Orange apples` after another 2 seconds, and then `Pink apples` after another 4 seconds

Comment: Its meant to remove one object from array on duration end, what it did for me is removed all items after longest duration

Comment: It should remove one at a time, check out this demo of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bswxm7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html Bear in mind I had to change `objArr.filter(...` to `objArr = objArr.filter(...`, as the filter function returns the filtered array instead of modifying the original. If you're still having issues, are you able to create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: Works, thank you for pointing that out! ...back to study basics for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one timer at a time. First sort array by time and then for smallest one set timer from `RxJs` (it's asynchronous). Call `applyTimer` from `constructor` or `ngOnInit`

> import {Observable} from "rxjs";

```
const objArr = [
  { key: 1, item: 'Orange apples', durationInMs: 4000 },
  { key: 2, item: 'Green apples', durationInMs: 2000 },
  { key: 3, item: 'Pink apples', durationInMs: 8000 },
];

sortArray() {
    objArr.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.durationInMs - b.durationInMs;
    }); 
}

applyTimer() {
    this.sortArray();
    if(this.objArr.length > 0) {
        Observable.timer(this.objArr[0].durationInMs).subscribe(x => {
            this.objArr = this.objArr.filter(element => element.key !== this.objArr[0].key);
            this.applyTimer();
        });
    }
}
```